# In garbage collection, what are the disadvantages of maintaining a list of inbound references?

Tags: garbage-collection

I'm working on a problem similar to that of garbage collection, where I need to be able to notify every object pointing to a particular object, should that object be moved elsewhere.

What are the pros and cons of just maintaining a list of all inbound references to an object?  Is this used in garbage collection algorithms?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard copying garbage collectors uses different technique to handle object relocations.  As it is traversing the object graph and copying objects, the first time it reaches an object via a some pointer it:

1. Copies the object to the new address (ex: address A).
2. Updates the pointer.
3. Mark the original object to say "moved to address A"

Now, every other time the GC reaches that object via a pointer, it'll see the "moved to address A" mark and update the pointer.

Adapting this to your use case, I think this would mean that objects would point to a relay pointer.  If you move the actual object, update the relay pointer with the new address.  With this technique, each access to an object has an extra step (to read the relay object) and moving the object is O(1).  The extra space used is O(number-of-objects).

With the incoming-pointers technique, each access has no overhead and moving the object is O(incoming-pointers).  The extra space used is O(number-of-pointers).

Comment: That technique of leaving a forwarder is commonly used in distributed systems, when you don't want the overhead of notifying every client when an object moves, and instead let clients know about the move lazily, when they next spontaneously connect to the object.

Comment: My system is a distributed system, however in this situation - when is it safe to remove the relay pointer?  Presumably they don't stick around forever.

Comment: @sanity: In a distributed systems, you often have timeouts to determine when a remote node is effectively dead.  You might be able to use a timeout-based mechanism to figure out when it's safe to discard the relay pointer.  If you provide more details of your exact setup maybe someone can help?

Comment: Thanks Kannan, I may submit a separate question

Comment: In some systems, when an object gets moved, some of the data space from the original object gets repurposed to reflect the object's new location.  This means that provided the objects have a minimum size, no extra storage is required to hold the replay pointer.